# Quicktime Playback Speed is not functioning

Tags: macos, video, quicktime

I am not able to change the playback speed in QuickTime Player on my MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur.

I know where the options are, but selecting different speeds has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't replicate the problem on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) & Big Sur. Both audio and video playback speed changes worked as expected. So it should be some specific issue.

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you for the input. It's funny, I'd never used it before recently, so I have only tried it on Big Sur. I don't know if it's a problem that arose following the upgrade, or if it was around before that and I just never knew.